# Нужна помощь в компилировании android проекта

Tags: android

Что имеем:

1. Есть [проект](https://github.com/libreliodev/android)
2. Установлен Eсlips
3. Добавлена виртуальная машина

В результате запуска проекта открывается стартовое окно и выскакивает ошибка (Application crashed). Подскажите, как правильно собрать проект?

Comment: в таких случаях очень полезно приложить logcat. Также, приложения лучше тестировать на реальном устройстве. Если на нем ошибки нет, тогда причина в эмуляторе.

Comment: Вам [сюда][1], вместе с стектрейсом ошибки.

  [1]: https://github.com/libreliodev/android/issues